# How to handle an <instance_controller> without a <skeleton> (FBX COLLADA exporter)

Tags: collada

The Collada specification explains that an instance_controller can have skeleton entries to define which subset of a joint hierarchy shall be searched to find the joints, like:

```
<node>
  <instance_controller url="#skin">
    <skeleton>#root</skeleton>
    <bind_material>...</bind_material>
  </instance_controller>
</node>
```

But it does not tell what to do when no such indication is available. For example the `<authoring_tool>FBX COLLADA exporter</authoring_tool>` omits the skeleton:

```
<node>
  <instance_controller url="#skin">
    <bind_material>...</bind_material>
  </instance_controller>
</node>
```

When i parse such Collada code with the OpenCollada framework, then i get

```
Sax FWL Error: Could not resolve sid ...
```

for every joint in the Joint hierarchy.
However Maya-2013 can import such collada with no issues. So is this a Bug in OpenCollada or a violation of the Collada specification from the FBX exporter ?

Answer (score 1):

Here’s what the spec says (1.4.1, page 5-114):

"Joints: Nodes specified by sid in the `<source>` referred to by the  (unshared) element with `semantic="JOINT"`. The `sid`s are typically stored in a `<Name_array>` where one name represents one `sid` (node). Upon instantiation of a skin controller, the `<skeleton>` elements define where to start the `sid` lookup. The joint matrices can be obtained at runtime from these nodes."

This means matching the names from the joint name array in the `<controller>` element with the `sid` of the joint nodes in the `<visual_scene>` is sufficient, the skeleton element just tells you explicitly where to start your search for the matching node `sid`s.

So, the FBX Exporter is producing a valid COLLADA file (as far as this case is concerned) that OpenCOLLADA should be able to read. Thanks to user2156664 for submitting an OpenCOLLADA patch.

That said, it is preferred to explicitly specify the root node where the matching `sid`s can be found in the `<skeleton>` element. The reason is that otherwise there is ambiguity potentially, or a need to have document-wide unique IDs for the node, which limits reuse of rigs, as marcus explained in http://collada.org/public_forum/showthread.php/1390-max-2011-collada-missing-skeleton-node?p=5395&viewfull=1#post5395. So this could still be considered as an FBX Exporter bug as well.

Answer (score 0):

So the short answer is: It seems to be a Bug in OpenCollada.

And the long answer:

I took a deep look into OpenCollada and actually the skinController code was prepared to search for all joints when no  entries where specified. It just did not work because of a bug that resulted in "no joints available for searching" instead of "search all joints". I created a patch for OpenCollada and sent a pull request to them.

Here is the link to the pull request: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCOLLADA/pull/209